# Displaying user input from a form in verification email

Tags: php

I'm having a little problem with my registration form: I am trying to get the UserID field displayed as inputted by the user when the verification email is sent for the user to activate the account.
Currently, I only need the *User provided* UserID and *randomly generated* PIN to be displayed in the verification email. Please can anyone correct this for me, as the PIN is displayed properly in the email, but not the UserID.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <!-- start PHP code -->
        <?php

            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with root .
            mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

            $email="";

            if( isset($_POST['fullname']) // Is the name field being posted; it does not matter whether it's empty or filled.  
    && // This is the same as the AND in our statement; it allows you to check multiple statements.  
    !empty($_POST['fullname']) // Verify if the field name is not empty 
    AND isset($_POST['email']) // Is the email field being posted; it does not matter if it's empty or filled.  
    && // This is the same as the AND in our statement; it allows you to check multiple statements.  
    !empty($_POST['email']) ) // Verify if the field email is not empty   
      {

                $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

                }
                if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)){
                    // Return Error - Invalid Email
                    $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';
                }else{
                    // Return Success - Valid Email
                    $msg = 'Your account has been created, <br /> please verify it by clicking the activation link that has been send to your email.';
                    }

                    $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.

                    $PIN = rand(1000,5000); // Generate random number between 1000 and 5000 and assign it to a local variable.

$to      = $email; // Send email to our user  
$subject = 'Signup | Verification of your BFS Account'; // Give the email a subject  
$message = 'Thanks for signing up! 
Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by clicking the url below. 
------------------------ 
USER ID: '.$UserID.' // **THIS IS WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM DISPLAYING USER ID**
PIN: '.$PIN.' 
------------------------ 
Please click this link to activate your account: 
http://www.website.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.' 
'; // Our message above including the link  
$headers = 'From:noreply@website.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers  
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email  

        ?>
        <!-- stop PHP Code -->           

    </div>
```

Comment: Where is $UserId assigned value?

Comment: I can't see any declaration, init, assignation, anything at all regarding the variable `$UserID`, where are you giving this variable its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to `$UserID`. As a wild guess you may need to:

```
$UserID = $_POST['userid']; //  or
$UserID = $_POST['user_id'];
```

P.S Please work on your code indentation.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how do I declare or assign UserID? Because unlike hash and PIN which I have declared, UserID is provided by the user and is to be simply retrieved from the form and sent to an email address.

Comment: I have declared UserID: $UserID = $_POST['UserID']; But I still get an error: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: UserID in C:\wamp\www\ONLINE BANKING\registration.php on line 528. I still can't think of what I'm doing wrong. P.S , sorry about the code indentation. I'm using notepad ++ and it's really not so easy to indent.

Comment: Ensure that you are form is sending 'UserID'. For example, you may need to add <input name='UserID' value='...'/>